# Why can "however" be used independently, when "but" cannot?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, language-change

According to Purdue OWL, there are two kinds of words that can be used as connectors at the beginning of independent clauses: coordinating conjunctions (so, yet, but, and) and independent marker words (however, also, therefore, nevertheless). Coordinating conjunctions require a preceding independent clause, but independent marker words can be used with just one independent clause.

There seem to be many similarities in meaning between words from the two groups. For example, "so" is similar to "therefore", and "but" is similar to "however".

How did these words become differentiated like that? Were independent markers always independent? I've noticed that many coordinating conjunctions are used independently now; are they eventually going to turn into independent marker words as well?

Comment: What do you mean by “_“however” be used independently, when “but” cannot_”?  Can't _every_ word be used independently?

Comment: But think of all the sentences which start with coordinating conjunctions.

Comment: The so-called ‘dependent’ markers have always been used independently – the notion that they require a preceding clause is, and has always been, nonsense.

Comment: Well, the meaning of these words guarantees that they always relate to some other proposition. I think it's clear though that they differ in syntax, and that there's a family resemblance within each group of words. I think it's reasonable to ask why that should be the case. Just saying that they're different words makes it impossible to account for the resemblance, and taking issue with the terminology of dependent / independent doesn't really help, unless a better way of describing the difference is put forward. OP's terminology may be wrong, but it's clear enough what he's driving at.

Comment: @rchivers - You've written quite a lengthy comment saying practically nothing substantial apart from the fact it's clear enough (for you) what the author's driving at. Would you, please, share that knowledge with the public? Have you noticed that I had already asked the author to explain what s/he's driving at?

Comment: What Purdue OWL says on but is nonsense. I'll just give you a quote (Zinsser 1976)  from the Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage (1994): "Many of us were taught that no sentence should begin with "but." If that's what you learned, unlearn it - there is no stronger word at the start. It announces total contrast with what has gone before, and the reader is primed for the change - Zinsser 1976."

Comment: Butterfield (Fowler's 4th ed.) adds, "Starting a sentence with *but*, as with *and*, is a not a matter of grammar but of style."

Comment: To clarify my question: nobody worries about beginning a sentence with "furthermore," but it is considered less formal/proper to begin a sentence with "and." If that seems a bit weak, punctuation at least distinguishes the two types of words: a comma comes before a coordinating conjunction, but a semicolon precedes a conjunctive adverb. I was wondering where the difference in use came from, whether the groups of words were always separate, and whether they will likely continue to be separate.

Comment: When people say, "Thank you so much...", as a non-native English user I used to wonder, 'How much?'  It is because, we learned that the standard way is "Thank you very much."  Yes, stylists have a different argument.  We wouldn't start a sentence with 'So', but these days people 'do'.  'Therefore' has always sounded like 'because of, in view of the foregoing, things being so',  etc., but 'SO' sounds a little open-ended, as if something more remains unsaid (if not said), like so.....as?, or so.....that?,  so that.....not? Or leaving it elliptical with three dots...? ...continues...

Comment: BUT is used in contrast with the previous contents, unlike HOWEVER which is more toned than BUT. You are a good candidate, but I cannot help you this time. You are a strong candidate; however, I have some limitations.  Again, stylists can have different views.  

While it is OK that certain use can bring in style(s), is it OK that everyone takes refuge in style even for an unprecedented or usually unacceptable style? I doubt.

Comment: If one has to deviate too much from conventions in the name of style, I may  refer it to one's inability to use language, the way it is. I never have felt anything less in English such that I have to take deviations and justify in the name of style(s).

Comment: “But” can be even the only word in a sentence, like in the following dialog. Jack: Mike, you're a good candidate... Mike: But?..

Comment: @YellowSky, But....the remaining is left to readers to guess; right? Thus, it is not a sentence, but just a word in a sentence. That way you are more right.  ;)

Comment: _However..._ gets used as a dramatic sentence fragment more often than _But..._ Three syllables with no unfortunate homonyms or euphemisms hanging out in the woodpile -- it's a no-brainer.